# Architecture: using Salesforce as a complete backend solution in this case?

Tags: web-services, architecture, client-server, salesforce

In our case we have less than a thousand users using company iPads. They need to update data on the server regularly and timely, with many fields across a variety of forms and versions of those forms. And irregularly download larger pieces of unrelated data for presentation. There are several relatively complex entities that we need to track, and more than usual cross-linkage between those entities. There are a number of systems that will need to feed into Salesforce as well as the client devices as above. There's also the question of middle tier (business logic) and where that will reside. To what extent might Salesforce limit/constrain our ability to do what we want? Where might it be really useful? What are the good architectural options I should be considering?

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce provides [API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index.htm) including Web Services via SOAP,Restful API and bulk API (for large data uploading, etc.) for your application to interact with their applications.

I am not sure if Salesforce will limit the number of API calls you can make each day or the volume of data you and upload/download to/from certain applications. You can follow up with them to check the details.

For you own architecture design, I think the layer serving your mobile clients might need to be hosted on your own site, then your have a backend business logic layer, hosted on your own site, but have certain logic talking to Saleforce.com servers. It's mainly integration considerations in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Do you plan on using a browser on the iPads or writing an application?

How large are the irregularly downloaded "larger pieces of unrelated data for presentation?"

Salesforce is perfectly capable of providing the middle tier of business logic.  You simply have to design the system in such a way that it isolates the data from the client requests.  Usually this is done by writing a service.

We've been especially successful doing that for Javascript and REST clients.

You're paying a lot of money for those licenses.  I'd like to insure you maximize the value of those licenses before adding other expenses with other platforms if they're unnecessary.

Comment: These will be native apps with some WebUI built in for accessing external links. The larger pieces can be a few megabytes, e.g. short video. We've also been looking at Kinvey for syncing with SF.